# request in ModelForm admin django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to create a default value in admin "add" form based on request (user attributes), searching I found that I can create default value overriding **init** method of ModelForm, however I can´t access to request here. Note: I tried self.request = kwargs.pop('request') and didn't work. Any Ideas, thaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the `render_change_form` method on your model admin:

```
def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):

    # your code here, modifying the values of whatever fields you have

    return super(YourModelAdmin, self).render_change_form(
        request, context, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks Brandom it´s works for me, inside the function `render_change_form` I can override the default value with: `context['adminform'].form.fields["name"].initial = ":D"`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, I jus create my stackoverflow account.